# Glance alway show null objc

Tags: ios, objective-c

I’m using Xcode 7b5.

I’ve read everything I could find on glances. But I still can’t get this simple thing to work.

My Glance always shows a null error inside of awakeWithContext in the watch simulator

I’m using Objective-C for the language.
I've imported WatchKit and WatchConnectivity

Here is the code in my ViewController on the iPhone:

```
// glance used on the watch
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group.testing.test"];
//set a value of SystemState for the key
[defaults setObject:SystemState forKey:@"SharingStatus"];
 // synchronise
[defaults synchronize];
```

The "SystemState" is just some text. In GlanceController.m I have this:

```
//use group user defaults
 NSUserDefaults *defaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group.testing.test"];

//get the object
NSString *statusData = [defaults objectForKey:@"SharingStatus"];
NSLog(@"Error = %@", statusData);
```

I have set up an app group for the main iPhone target as well using that same group for the watch extension target.

My developer account shows the App Group does indeed exist.

On the phone side in code I can find the App Group Preferences on disk using this:

```
[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:@"group.testing.test"] relativePath]);
```

So I know “SystemState” value is saving to the shared folder

But for whatever reason the Glance always returns null. Now I am lost. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

NSUserDefaults doesn't work between your iOS app and the WatchKit extension on watchOS 2 as the processes are running on separate devices. You will have to use the WatchConnectivity framework APIs to transfer the content and changes.

To learn why this is necessary, and how to do this I'd suggest starting with watching some of the general WatchKit WWDC videos and then moving on to the WatchConnectivity one.